# Make prolog ignore alternatives, but still backtrack

Tags: prolog

So I have a recursive predicate that looks like this:

```
top_predicate(A, B, C):-
   finish(A, B, C).
top_predicate(A, B, C):-
   sub_predicate_1(B,E),
   E > 10,
   predicate(D, E, F).
top_predicate(A,B,C):-
   % some other predicate
   predicate(D,E,F).
```

sub_predicate_1 has a lot of alternatives. I would like Prolog to only consider the first answer it gets from sub_predicate_1, but still be able to back track behind it. This is because if sub_predicate_1's first answer is less than or equal to 10 then all of them will be. The first answer is the best answer always.

I have tried adding a cut here:

```
predicate(A, B, C):-
   sub_predicate_1(B,E),
   E > 10,!,
   predicate(D, E, F).
```

But if, during some recursions, E > 10 fails and the program backtracks to the third definition of top_predicate and that fails then the entire program fails.

I have tried adding a cut in sub_predicate_1 (while also pulling the E > 10 condition inside) but it yields the same effect. Is what I am asking for possible?

Forgive the highly abstracted question, I want to know why it would or wouldn't work rather than someone just fix it for me. If you require more information please ask.

Comment: Wrap the main invocation into `once/1`, i.e., run: `?- once(your_predicate(Solution)).`. This will only give you the first solution, and still keep your predicate general. Do not destroy the semantics of the whole predicate only because you just need one solution!

Comment: @mat How did I miss this? Thank you very much.